# Dynamic SQL Query using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, dynamic-sql

Here is the updated query as per the suggestions in the thread:

```
DECLARE
    @table      sysname,
    @sql        nvarchar(max),
    @dbname     sysname;

SELECT @dbname = MAX(dbname) 
FROM ACVSCore.dbo.ACVSUJournalVolumeManagement.dbname
WHERE ACVSCore.dbo.ACVSUJournalVolumeManagement LIKE '%ACVSUJournal%';

SELECT @table = N'.dbo.ACVSUJournalLog';

SET @sql = N'SELECT 
    ap.LastName as [Last Name],
    ap.FirstName as [First Name],
    ap.Text1 as [Company],
    ap.Text2 as [Employee ID],
    tn.ObjectName2 as [Door Name],
    MIN(tn.ServerUTC) AS [ServerUTC]
FROM ' + @dbname + @table + N' tn 
INNER JOIN 
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel ap on tn.objectidentity1 = 
    ap.GUID
WHERE
    ap.PersonnelTypeID = ''2'' and tn.MessageType
    = ''CardAdmitted'' and tn.ServerUTC >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    ap.Text1, ap.LastName, ap.FirstName, ap.Text2, tn.ObjectName2
ORDER BY 
    ap.Text1'
EXECUTE
    sp_executesql @sql;
```

I edited the query to reflect the changes suggested and it works without issue now. Thank you again!

Comment: Don't use string literals for aliases and this problem actually disappears; it's a bad habit in my opinion anyway as it causes confuses for some.

Comment: The single quotes on column labels are causing problems.  It could be said they're not properly escaped but they shouldn't be there at all.  The correct way to delimit object names is with brackets []

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/); alias your objects and qualify your columns that way.

Comment: @SteveC note, that the *standard* way is `"`

Comment: Finally, don't just inject the objects into your code. *Securely* inject them with `QUOTENAME`. Also, the correct data type for object names is `sysname`, not `nvarchar(255)`

Comment: Why is there a comma after `ACVSCore.dbo.ACVSUJournalVolumeManagement.dbname`?

Comment: There are a lot of typos it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my [EDIT: latest] attempt to fix the typos

```
DECLARE
  @table      sysname,
  @sql        nvarchar(max),
  @dbname     sysname;

select @dbname = MAX(dbname) 
from ACVSCore.dbo.ACVSUJournalVolumeManagement 
where ACVSCore.dbo.ACVSUJournalVolumeManagement LIKE '%ACVSUJournalLog%';

select @table = N'.dbo.ACVSUJournalLog';

SET @sql = N'SELECT 
    ap.LastName as [Last Name],
    ap.FirstName as [First Name],
    ap.Text1 as [Company],
    ap.Text2 as [Employee ID],
    tn.ObjectName2 as [Door Name],
    MIN(tn.ServerUTC) AS [ServerUTC]
FROM ' + @dbname + @table + N' tn 
INNER JOIN 
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel ap on tn.objectidentity1 = 
    ap.GUID
WHERE
    ap.PersonnelTypeID = ''2'' and tn.MessageType
     = ''CardAdmitted'' and tn.ServerUTC >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    ap.Text1, ap.LastName, ap.FirstName, ap.Text2, tn.ObjectName2
ORDER BY 
    ap.Text1'
EXECUTE
    sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I updated the original post and included an image of what happens when executing the query --> I had to remove the concat as it was running the query against the database name twice example: ACVSUdatabaseACVSUDatabase.ACVSUJournalLog

Comment: You need `QUOTENAME` for the DB name

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `'` in aliases

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT 
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel.LastName as [Last Name],
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel.FirstName as [First Name],
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel.Text1 as [Company],
    ACVSCore.Access.Personnel.Text2 as [Employee ID],
    dbo.ACVSUJournalLog.ObjectName2 as [Door Name],
    MIN(dbo.ACVSUJournalLog.ServerUTC) AS [ServerUTC]
FROM ' + @dbname + @table
```